Canvas size stretched compared to the original image
I created a plugin for my wordpress site. The way this plugin works is that when a variant is selected and then "custom" is selected as the size, a section opens where I can enter the dimensions and select the portion of the image.
The problem is that this image is not the same size as the original but is taller and therefore the image is stretched. How can I solve it?
  function getSourceCanvas(image, data) {
    var canvas = $('<canvas>')[0];
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var dstX = 0;
    var dstY = 0;
    var dstWidth = data.naturalWidth;
    var dstHeight = data.naturalHeight;
    var rotate = data.rotate;
    var scaleX = data.scaleX;
    var scaleY = data.scaleY;
    var scalable = isNumber(scaleX) && isNumber(scaleY) && (scaleX !== 1 || scaleY !== 1);
    var rotatable = isNumber(rotate) && rotate !== 0;
    var advanced = rotatable || scalable;
    var canvasWidth = dstWidth * abs(scaleX || 1);
    var canvasHeight = dstHeight * abs(scaleY || 1);
    var translateX;
    var translateY;
    var rotated;

    if (scalable) {
      translateX = canvasWidth / 2;
      translateY = canvasHeight / 2;
    }

    if (rotatable) {
      rotated = getRotatedSizes({
        width: canvasWidth,
        height: canvasHeight,
        degree: rotate
      });

      canvasWidth = rotated.width;
      canvasHeight = rotated.height;
      translateX = canvasWidth / 2;
      translateY = canvasHeight / 2;
    }

    canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasHeight;

    if (advanced) {
      dstX = -dstWidth / 2;
      dstY = -dstHeight / 2;

      context.save();
      context.translate(translateX, translateY);
    }

    // Scale should come first before rotate (#633, #709)
    if (scalable) {
      context.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
    }

    if (rotatable) {
      context.rotate(rotate * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    context.drawImage(image, floor(dstX), floor(dstY), floor(dstWidth), floor(dstHeight));

    if (advanced) {
      context.restore();
    }

    return canvas;
  }

  function getTouchesCenter(touches) {
    var length = touches.length;
    var pageX = 0;
    var pageY = 0;

    if (length) {
      $.each(touches, function (i, touch) {
        pageX += touch.pageX;
        pageY += touch.pageY;
      });

      pageX /= length;
      pageY /= length;
    }

    return {
      pageX: pageX,
      pageY: pageY
    };
  }

    // Canvas (image wrapper)
    initCanvas: function () {
      var viewMode = this.options.viewMode;
      var container = this.container;
      var containerWidth = container.width;
      var containerHeight = container.height;
      var image = this.image;
      var imageNaturalWidth = image.naturalWidth;
      var imageNaturalHeight = image.naturalHeight;
      var is90Degree = abs(image.rotate) === 90;
      var naturalWidth = is90Degree ? imageNaturalHeight : imageNaturalWidth;
      var naturalHeight = is90Degree ? imageNaturalWidth : imageNaturalHeight;
      var aspectRatio = naturalWidth / naturalHeight;
      var canvasWidth = containerWidth;
      var canvasHeight = containerHeight;
      var canvas;

      if (containerHeight * aspectRatio > containerWidth) {
        if (viewMode === 3) {
          canvasWidth = containerHeight * aspectRatio;
        } else {
          canvasHeight = containerWidth / aspectRatio;
        }
      } else {
        if (viewMode === 3) {
          canvasHeight = containerWidth / aspectRatio;
        } else {
          canvasWidth = containerHeight * aspectRatio;
        }
      }

      canvas = {
        naturalWidth: naturalWidth,
        naturalHeight: naturalHeight,
        aspectRatio: aspectRatio,
        width: canvasWidth,
        height: canvasHeight
      };

      canvas.oldLeft = canvas.left = (containerWidth - canvasWidth) / 2;
      canvas.oldTop = canvas.top = (containerHeight - canvasHeight) / 2;

      this.canvas = canvas;
      this.isLimited = (viewMode === 1 || viewMode === 2);
      this.limitCanvas(true, true);
      this.initialImage = $.extend({}, image);
      this.initialCanvas = $.extend({}, canvas);
    },

    limitCanvas: function (isSizeLimited, isPositionLimited) {
      var options = this.options;
      var viewMode = options.viewMode;
      var container = this.container;
      var containerWidth = container.width;
      var containerHeight = container.height;
      var canvas = this.canvas;
      var aspectRatio = canvas.aspectRatio;
      var cropBox = this.cropBox;
      var isCropped = this.isCropped && cropBox;
      var minCanvasWidth;
      var minCanvasHeight;
      var newCanvasLeft;
      var newCanvasTop;

      if (isSizeLimited) {
        minCanvasWidth = num(options.minCanvasWidth) || 0;
        minCanvasHeight = num(options.minCanvasHeight) || 0;

        if (viewMode) {
          if (viewMode > 1) {
            minCanvasWidth = max(minCanvasWidth, containerWidth);
            minCanvasHeight = max(minCanvasHeight, containerHeight);

            if (viewMode === 3) {
              if (minCanvasHeight * aspectRatio > minCanvasWidth) {
                minCanvasWidth = minCanvasHeight * aspectRatio;
              } else {
                minCanvasHeight = minCanvasWidth / aspectRatio;
              }
            }
          } else {
            if (minCanvasWidth) {
              minCanvasWidth = max(minCanvasWidth, isCropped ? cropBox.width : 0);
            } else if (minCanvasHeight) {
              minCanvasHeight = max(minCanvasHeight, isCropped ? cropBox.height : 0);
            } else if (isCropped) {
              minCanvasWidth = cropBox.width;
              minCanvasHeight = cropBox.height;

              if (minCanvasHeight * aspectRatio > minCanvasWidth) {
                minCanvasWidth = minCanvasHeight * aspectRatio;
              } else {
                minCanvasHeight = minCanvasWidth / aspectRatio;
              }
            }
          }
        }

        if (minCanvasWidth && minCanvasHeight) {
          if (minCanvasHeight * aspectRatio > minCanvasWidth) {
            minCanvasHeight = minCanvasWidth / aspectRatio;
          } else {
            minCanvasWidth = minCanvasHeight * aspectRatio;
          }
        } else if (minCanvasWidth) {
          minCanvasHeight = minCanvasWidth / aspectRatio;
        } else if (minCanvasHeight) {
          minCanvasWidth = minCanvasHeight * aspectRatio;
        }

        canvas.minWidth = minCanvasWidth;
        canvas.minHeight = minCanvasHeight;
        canvas.maxWidth = Infinity;
        canvas.maxHeight = Infinity;
      }

      if (isPositionLimited) {
        if (viewMode) {
          newCanvasLeft = containerWidth - canvas.width;
          newCanvasTop = containerHeight - canvas.height;

          canvas.minLeft = min(0, newCanvasLeft);
          canvas.minTop = min(0, newCanvasTop);
          canvas.maxLeft = max(0, newCanvasLeft);
          canvas.maxTop = max(0, newCanvasTop);

          if (isCropped && this.isLimited) {
            canvas.minLeft = min(
              cropBox.left,
              cropBox.left + cropBox.width - canvas.width
            );
            canvas.minTop = min(
              cropBox.top,
              cropBox.top + cropBox.height - canvas.height
            );
            canvas.maxLeft = cropBox.left;
            canvas.maxTop = cropBox.top;

            if (viewMode === 2) {
              if (canvas.width >= containerWidth) {
                canvas.minLeft = min(0, newCanvasLeft);
                canvas.maxLeft = max(0, newCanvasLeft);
              }

              if (canvas.height >= containerHeight) {
                canvas.minTop = min(0, newCanvasTop);
                canvas.maxTop = max(0, newCanvasTop);
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          canvas.minLeft = -canvas.width;
          canvas.minTop = -canvas.height;
          canvas.maxLeft = containerWidth;
          canvas.maxTop = containerHeight;
        }
      }
    },

    renderCanvas: function (isChanged) {
      var canvas = this.canvas;
      var image = this.image;
      var rotate = image.rotate;
      var naturalWidth = image.naturalWidth;
      var naturalHeight = image.naturalHeight;
      var aspectRatio;
      var rotated;

      if (this.isRotated) {
        this.isRotated = false;

        // Computes rotated sizes with image sizes
        rotated = getRotatedSizes({
          width: image.width,
          height: image.height,
          degree: rotate
        });

        aspectRatio = rotated.width / rotated.height;

        if (aspectRatio !== canvas.aspectRatio) {
          canvas.left -= (rotated.width - canvas.width) / 2;
          canvas.top -= (rotated.height - canvas.height) / 2;
          canvas.width = rotated.width;
          canvas.height = rotated.height;
          canvas.aspectRatio = aspectRatio;
          canvas.naturalWidth = naturalWidth;
          canvas.naturalHeight = naturalHeight;

          // Computes rotated sizes with natural image sizes
          if (rotate % 180) {
            rotated = getRotatedSizes({
              width: naturalWidth,
              height: naturalHeight,
              degree: rotate
            });

            canvas.naturalWidth = rotated.width;
            canvas.naturalHeight = rotated.height;
          }

          this.limitCanvas(true, false);
        }
      }

      if (canvas.width > canvas.maxWidth || canvas.width < canvas.minWidth) {
        canvas.left = canvas.oldLeft;
      }

      if (canvas.height > canvas.maxHeight || canvas.height < canvas.minHeight) {
        canvas.top = canvas.oldTop;
      }

      canvas.width = min(max(canvas.width, canvas.minWidth), canvas.maxWidth);
      canvas.height = min(max(canvas.height, canvas.minHeight), canvas.maxHeight);

      this.limitCanvas(false, true);

      canvas.oldLeft = canvas.left = min(max(canvas.left, canvas.minLeft), canvas.maxLeft);
      canvas.oldTop = canvas.top = min(max(canvas.top, canvas.minTop), canvas.maxTop);

      this.$canvas.css({
        top: canvas.top
        });

      this.renderImage();

      if (this.isCropped && this.isLimited) {
        this.limitCropBox(true, true);
      }

      if (isChanged) {
        this.output();
      }
    },

    renderImage: function (isChanged) {
      var canvas = this.canvas;
      var image = this.image;
      var reversed;

      if (image.rotate) {
        reversed = getRotatedSizes({
          width: canvas.width,
          height: canvas.height,
          degree: image.rotate,
          aspectRatio: image.aspectRatio
        }, true);
      }

      $.extend(image, reversed ? {
        width: reversed.width,
        height: reversed.height,
        left: (canvas.width - reversed.width) / 2,
        top: (canvas.height - reversed.height) / 2
      } : {
        width: canvas.width,
        height: canvas.height,
        left: 0,
        top: 0
      });

      if (isChanged) {
        this.output();
      }
    },

